# can't create playlists after creating a channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels, json-c

**Name of API affected:**

YouTube Data API 2.1

**Issue summary:**

I am running into issues with youtube accounts that are unlinked.
First I successfully create a channel for an account through the youtube gdata api.
Then when I try to create a playlist for the same account, it fails with an error 403, youtube_signup_required.  If I wait for hours to a day, then eventually it works.
Is there a considerable delay between when an account is linked and when I can use it?
I can go directly to youtube and create a playlist there with no problem.
I can even manipulate that playlist(add videos etc...) with the api immediately after, just not create new playlists.

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. link an account by creating a channel for it through the gdata api
2. try to create a playlist for that same account through the gdata api

**Expected output:**

successfully create a new playlist for a recently linked account

**Actual results:**

a 403 youtube_signup_required error

Comment: I'm moving this issue over from the gdata-issues forum in hopes that it'll get answered here

Comment: I'm still waiting to hear back from the engineering team, and http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2979 will be kept up to date on the status. It's not a great idea to cross-post bug reports to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mobile workflow in a WebView to have the user create the channel without leaving your app:

https://m.youtube.com/create_channel?chromeless=1&next=/channel_creation_done

To process will take the user to /channel_creation_done once completed, and you can close the WebView then. You can find more information about the workflow here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel. Can you please try this one instead?

Comment: seems like WebView is limited to mobile devices, so not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately using a different workflow isn't an option.  Our project is on hold until the current workflow bug is fixed